# What is the Intution behind eigen vector in context of Google Page rank Algorithm?

Tags: machine-learning, eigenvalues, pagerank

I am trying to understand the intuition behind Eigen Values and vectors. Theoretically, I understand that a linear transformation can be understood as scaling for special vectors and those special vectors are called eigen vectors and the scaling factor is eigen value.

To understand the intution from real world application, I started to read [this resource](https://www.rose-hulman.edu/%7Ebryan/googleFinalVersionFixed.pdf) that explains how the concepts of linear algebra were used in making page rank algorithm responsible for the better ranked results. This explains formation of a square matrix A (which is a links matrix of web pages normalised). However what I do not understand is

1. Reasoning behind the conclusion that importance vector of web pages is eigen vector of eigen value 1 (*We thus seek an eigenvector x with eigenvalue 1 for the
   matrix A* (page 3 from the resource)?
2. What about eigen vector for eigen value 2, 3, 4 and 5?
3. How is above related to scaling funda of eigen vectors and eigen vectors?

Request your inputs to concretize the understanding.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer to question 1: Reasoning behind the conclusion that importance vector of web pages is eigen vector of eigen value 1**

The link matrix has elements = [Link to the corresponding page]/total.
This matrix has 2 properties:

1. Each element is <= 1
2. Columns adds to 1.

Such a matrix is called Markov Matrix and this kind of matrix will definitely have an eigenvalue of 1. The steady state for this matrix will correspond to this eigenvalue of 1 (discussed [here](https://youtu.be/lGGDIGizcQ0?t=189))

**Answer to Question 2: What about eigen vector for eigen value 2, 3, 4 and 5?**

The other eigen values in this case will be less than 1

**Question 3: How is above related to scaling funda of eigen vectors and eigen vectors?**

In this particular case, we are trying to know the steady state. Thus, the scaling funda doesnt apply here.